# How do I find what versions of npm and node my dependencies need?

Tags: node.js, npm

When doing a npm install, I was getting some node-gyp errors that recommended I update to the latest version of node. So I updated my Node and NPM to the latest version. This did not fix the problem. Now, I'm trying to run a node app that was working previously, but I guess due to the differences in versions, I'm getting this error "Failed at the serialport@1.7.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'."

When I try to start the app, I get these errors.

```
    /Users/grace/code/CreativeCode/FinalProject/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 51.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/Users/grace/code/CreativeCode/FinalProject/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/grace/code/CreativeCode/FinalProject/node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

I think to solve this, I should revert to the npm and node versions I had before, but I don't know which it is. Please help! None of the node apps I built work now because of this problem.

Comment: Every time you switch node versions you need to recompile the dependencies. This can be done with `npm install`, but preferably before that you need to remove the whole `node_modules` path in your project. So `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but got these errors. 

Also, how do I npm install only the dependencies listed in the package.json file? Now npm install is installing a bunch of things I didn't have in my node modules folder before

Comment: to install just dependencies "npm install"

Comment: https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/issues/649 visit this for more detail